# HTTP requests in Express NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I have the following code from https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/:

```
  this.get("/hola", function(res) {
    iniciar();
  });

  function iniciar() {
    self.init();
  }
  iniciar();
```

going to `localhost:8080/hola`, it does not load. `localhost:8080` works perfectly. `self.init()` calls a function that, in turn, calls other functions. The problem seems to be the following called function:

```
Server.prototype.initMiddleware = function() {
  var self = this
    , conf = this.conf;

  this.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var setHeader = res.setHeader;
    res.setHeader = function(name) {
      switch (name) {
        case 'Cache-Control':
        case 'Last-Modified':
        case 'ETag':
          return;
      }
      return setHeader.apply(res, arguments);
    };
    next();
  });

  this.use(function(req, res, next) {
    return self._auth(req, res, next);
  });

  this.use(term.middleware());
  this.use(this.app.router);
  this.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../static'));
};
```

According to `express.js` documentation:

```
// a middleware sub-stack which prints request info for any type of HTTP request to /user/:id
app.use('/user/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl);
  next();
}, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
  next();
});
```

So, it seems that there are "conflicts" between first `app.get` and the others `app.use` or `this.use`. How can I solve that?

Comment: Do you really just want to make `localhost:8080/hola` behave just like `localhost:8080/`? You can simply copy `static/index.html` into `static/hola` and you've made a copy of your index file into another file. The Express server serves the static HTML of the terminal app directly from the `/static` folder; the server-side logic you're tinkering with only specifies how to respond to requests from the static HTML client, not how to send the base client code to the browser.

Comment: To help you understand your actual problem, `self.init()` here sets up server-side logic. Basically, you've made it so that you need to visit `/hola` before the main page (`/`) will work, but visiting `/hola` doesn't do anything else by itself (other than enabling the app to work at all). Only that's not even true, because you've already run `self.init()` outside of the `app.get('hola')` listener anyway (with `iniciar()`), so visiting `/hola` does absolutely nothing at all.

Comment: @apsillers, about your comment, you are suggesting that `this.get("/", function(res) {iniciar();});` and deleting `self.init` outside `app.get` would work. But it isn't.

Comment: Do this: **1.** Put the code back the way you found it (for now). You don't need to alter server-side logic for what you want to do, and it's likely to *stop* this form working until you have a setup that works for sure. **2.** Copy `static/index.html` into a new file, `static/hola`.  **3.** Load `localhost:8080/hola` in your browser.

Comment: OK, @apsillers, it does NOT work. My aim is to setup a more secure login for this app, such as http://passportjs.org/. Thus, I need passport to redirect the users using `get` when the login is successful.

Answer (score -1):

it's because you are not returnig anything and then the browser is polling this until it return something.

```
this.app.get("/hola", function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/html'});
    res.end('/*html code here*/');
  });
```

Comment: `self.init()` returns a lot of things when it is called outside `app.get(...)`. `self.init()` calls functions that, in turn, call other functions. Finally, I get an output. The problem is that with `app.get`, it does not work.

Comment: @user2979409 "*`self.init()` returns a lot of things*" It doesn't, because it doesn't have a `return` statement. It may print a lot to a console, or perform many other side-effect actions, but it does not `return` anything. The value of a function expression call like `self.init()` is the `return` value of the function being called.

Comment: @apsillers, and why I see a bash console "printed" in my browser, if it does not return anything? (`self.init` called outside `app.get(...)`. What I want is the same output calling `self.init` or calling `app.get('/', function() {self.init()});`

Comment: i disagree. but i think that in this case i don't see what those methods are doing because you are not setting them:
`if (this.conf.localOnly) this.initLocal();
  this.initMiddleware();
  this.initRoutes();
  this.initIO();`

Comment: @user2979409 What does a function's `return` value have to do with the side-effect action of printing to a console? If you don't call `return`, there's no defined `return` value. You can call `console.log` in a function and not call `return` in that function. (For example, define a function: `function foo() { console.log("I'm a log statement!"); }` and then call it: `var result = foo();` When you log the value of `result`, note that it is `undefined`. the return value has nothing to do with anything else the function does.)

Comment: @user2979409 What you want to do is replace the current console-logging logging behavior with HTTP response-writing behavior. Find the function that writes to the console and replace it with a function that writes to an HTTP response. (Re: "*even calling return, it does not work*", *what* are you returning? If you `return 5;`, then you will write an HTTP response that contains the message `5`. If you `return "foo"`, the message will be `foo`. If you `return something()` then the message will be whatever `something` returns.)

Comment: @ariel_556, this code is part of https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/blob/master/lib/tty.js

Comment: the thing is that you aren't using wisely this code:
function iniciar() {
    self.init();
  }

Comment: @apsillers, I return a function that should give something to the screen, and it does when calling it outside `app.get`. It is not so complicated to understand.

Comment: @user2979409 And it still *does* output to the console in either case, doesn't it? It doesn't matter whether you include `self.init()` inside of `app.get` or not; the behavior is identical, right? You actually want the behavior to *change* when you put it inside of `app.get` (i.e., you expect an HTTP response to be sent to your browser instead of a console message written to your bash console). Writing to a console and sending an HTTP response are different actions; you can change your code to do one instead of the other, but you'll need to change how the code sends messages.

Comment: in this case if you want to execute any of those methods in `init();` you could call them `this.app.get("/hola", function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/html'});
    res.end(that.initLocal());
  });`

Comment: the behaviour IS NOT IDENTICAL, @apsillers. Outside `app.get`, I get a terminal "printed" in my screen, in my BROWSER. Inside `app.get`, it never loads.

Comment: it does not work, @ariel_556, `that` is not defined.

Comment: @user2979409 I see; by "bash console" I assumed you meant OS-level instance of the console program `bash` that was running your node.js script. I see now that you mean something entirely different.

Comment: @user2979409 It would clarify matters greatly to edit your question to explain precisely how the behavior differs from expected behavior. For a start, include that link in your question, and go on to edit the question the information that we've pulled out here in the comments. Your actual problem is non-obvious to potential answerers, in part because it's ambiguous what you meant by "bash shell" (instead, you should say "the tty.js shell does not render when I make its initialization contingent on an HTTP request" or similar).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64961/discussion-on-answer-by-ariel-556-the-tty-js-shell-does-not-render-when-i-make-i).